# Magento : Add text fields to selected multiselect options

Tags: jquery, magento, e-commerce, php

I have a multiselect attribute, say **Marks**.
Now I have added subjects as

```
Sub1
Sub2
Sub3
Sub4
```

as Options for it.

The problem is, in the Admin panel, when the user select **Sub 1, Sub 2** options for a particular product, I need another field nearby to enter % of marks.

Marks are different for different products, so I can't set them in labels of Marks attribute

Consider I have a huge number of subjects

What I require in backend, when Sub 1, Sub 2 is selected

```
Sub1 -> 87%
Sub2 -> 52%
```

If Ajax, I am happy,
adjustable even it comes in a button click...

Please help me...
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not support this out of the box.
You may need to create a custom template for your attribute where you can add you javascript that adds a new text field each time you select a value for the multiselect and save those values serialized in the database.
[Here is an example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38445/146) of how you can create an attribute with a custom template.
It's kind of long to replicate in here.
The main idea is to create a custom backend model for you attribute that will serialize the values on save and unserialize them on load, and a custom rendered that will display the multiselect and the fields for each value in the admin UI.